# How can I save multiple user inputs into variables in Python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a silly calculator using Tkinter, and I have a global variable called "phrase". So basically, I have buttons (meaningless names), and I just want to add/subtract and print out sentences, such as "banana" + "milk" = "banana milk!" But I'm having difficulties saving user's inputs into global variable "phrase". Below is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

phrase = ''


# To press any button
def press(item):
    global phrase
    if item == 'Banana':
        phrase = 'This is yellow'
    elif item == 'Milk':
        phrase = 'This is white'
    return equation.set(phrase)

############################### Here is the fucntion adding together
def recipe(item):
    global phrase
    if item == 'AND':
        phrase = phrase + ' ' + str(item)
        equation.set(phrase)



# Driver code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create application window
    app = Tk()

    # title
    app.title("Silly Calculator")

    # geometry
    app.geometry('290x162')

    # background color
    app.configure(bg='pink')

    equation = StringVar()
    windows = Entry(app, textvariable=equation)
    windows.grid(columnspan=5, ipadx=100, ipady=10)
    equation.set('Listen to your Funculator!')

    # Create buttons and other accessories
    button1 = Button(app, text='Banana', fg='yellow', bg='purple',
                     command=lambda: press('Banana'), height=2, width=10)
    button1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

    button2 = Button(app, text='Milk', fg='brown', bg='pink',
                     command=lambda: press('Milk'), height=2, width=10)
    button2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="NSEW")

    plus = Button(app, text='AND', fg='black', bg='white',
                  command=lambda: recipe('AND'), height=2, width=10)
    plus.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

# start the GUI
app.mainloop()
```

So I tried to make the global variable phase to a list [], and maybe access by the index number. But that does not work, and I only get one last user-input saved to "phrase". Is there a way that I can save in different variables such as phrase_1, phrase_2 so that I can use these when:

```
# This is enter
def recipe(item):
    global phrase
    if item == 'AND':
        phrase = phrase_1 + phrase_2
        equation.set(phrase)
```

like this?

Any advice will be appreciated!!

Comment: You can use `Checkbutton` for the recipients instead of `Button`.  Then you can check which recipients are checked and construct the required recipe.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about Check button....!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? Or I didn't understand correctly?

```
from tkinter import *

phrase = []
phrase_string = ''


# To press any button
def press(item):
    global phrase_string
    global phrase

    if item == 'Banana':
        phrase.append(' Banana')
    elif item == 'Milk':
        phrase.append(' Milk')
    elif item == 'AND':
        phrase.append(' and')

    phrase_string = ''
    for ele in phrase:
        phrase_string += ele

    equation.set(phrase_string)



# Driver code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create application window
    app = Tk()

    # title
    app.title("Silly Calculator")

    # geometry
    app.geometry('290x162')

    # background color
    app.configure(bg='pink')

    equation = StringVar()
    windows = Entry(app, textvariable=equation)
    windows.grid(columnspan=5, ipadx=100, ipady=10)

    # Create buttons and other accessories
    button1 = Button(app, text='Banana', fg='yellow', bg='purple',
                     command=lambda: press('Banana'), height=2, width=10)
    button1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

    button2 = Button(app, text='Milk', fg='brown', bg='pink',
                     command=lambda: press('Milk'), height=2, width=10)
    button2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="NSEW")

    plus = Button(app, text='AND', fg='black', bg='white',
                  command=lambda: press('AND'), height=2, width=10)
    plus.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ohh it seems like I can do that way. But the user input shows in []. Can I get rid of []? And just get the text out of it?

Comment: I edited the code and added how to convert a list `phrase = []` to string `phrase_string = ''`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I changed my code according to yours and actually I understand so much better now.

Comment: I am glad to hear that. Add a comment, if you will have any more concerns.

Comment: Hi I have another question! So,  I want to make every button to be only able to click once, so for example, no double digits such as 12, 13 but just 1 + 3 and so on.. What kind of function can it do this? Since my calculator has strings, like banana and milk, I don't wnat to type (banana banana + milk) but instead only (banana + milk).. if you can understand me.

Comment: Post the full code, if you have changed something. I will help you, when I will be back home.

Comment: Hi!! I just posted it. Whenever you're available! I'm going to work on my codes while waiting.

Comment: I added the answer.

Comment: Thank you I just checked your answer, I'm outside but I will look at it when I get home. Thank you so much for helping me!!!!! Hope you're staying healthy and safe wherever you are :-D